# How to launch Hangouts conversations from contact name or conversation ID?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts, google-hangouts

I've got an issue that's got me stuck for the past few days. I want to be able to open specific conversations in Hangouts from my own 3rd party app. So far I've only been able to open conversations by launching an SMS intent, but those intents often start new conversations, not open existing ones, so that doesn't really help me.

**Approach with `PendingIntent`:** My app hooks into the notification service, and from there I can get a `PendingIntent` to open a conversation. That essentially does what I am looking for. However, when there are multiple new messages, then the `PendingIntent` just opens Hangouts, not any particular conversation. I also can't hold onto the `PendingIntent` between phone reboots. So while this works for one message, I don't see how this could scale up. Could it?

**Approach with Conversation ID:** From the `PendingIntent`, I can also get specific conversation IDs for each conversation. I was hoping to be able to plug the ID into a URL (*eg*, `https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/UgwTtVFQbZXPXgVbQs94AaABAQ`), and then launch that as the URI for an intent, but that doesn't work either. It does open Hangouts, but it opens a broken video call. I've been looking through the Hangouts `AndroidManifest.xml` for other possible URLs, but everything I've tried so far has failed.

**Approach with Phone Contacts:** The last approach I've tried is to take the name/phone/email of the person in the Hangouts conversation, look it up the in the phone's contacts, and then try to pass data that to Hangouts in the hopes that it would open the right conversation. I know this won't work when the conversation is not in the phone's contacts, but that's a concession I can make. I was inspired to try this approach by what I've seen from Tasker, and in particular, the first few minutes of [this video](https://youtu.be/o49wpYoeV6U). It's possible that this should work and I'm simply not doing it the right way, but so far this has been a no go.

I've also thought about opening Hangouts normally, then using the Accessibility Service to simulate user input to manually navigate to the conversation that matches the name. However, this seems like a really error-prone and heavy-handed approach.

Am I missing something obvious? It seems like there should be a clean way to do this, to launch an intent that tells Hangouts to open the ongoing conversation for So-and-So. What have I missed?

Comment: One thing you could try doing is seeing if Hangouts actually exposes the ContentProvider (which I doubt) but maybe there is something possible there. But you'd have to get familiar with their already pre-existing tables and structure. In order to figure that out you'd need to basically look at their manifest, which may be possible by using PackageManager APIs. Or maybe if you're lucky you can decompile the APK and see the manifest that way.